# How to generate two correlated random samples, one follows geometric Brownian motion, the other follows a beta distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, sampling, random-variable, monte-carlo

I'd like to conduct a Monte Carlo simulation with two random variables.

One random variable is generated by geometric Brownian motion, the other random variable is sampled by drawing random values from a Beta distribution. The two variables should be correlated.

My questions are:

How to model the correlation between the two random variables? Is Copula a direction that I should look into?

How to simulate the two variables in Python? Is there any package that would be helpful?

Comment: Is there a specific, exact type of correlation you need? Or is any convenient parametrizable sort of correlation OK?

Comment: A Brownian motion is not a random variable but a random function. How do you define the correlation for such an object?

Comment: Hi jwimberley and Xi'an, thank you for pointing out this! The correlation here is defined as a simple linear correlation captured by Pearson correlation coefficient

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that any convenient parametrizable sort of correlation suffices, here is a workable model whose details you can flesh out.

A straightforward way to generate correlated standard-normally distributed variables is via a Cholesky decomposition. Various instructions can be found for this online or in CrossValidated. See, for example,

[How to use the Cholesky decomposition, or an alternative, for correlated data simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160054/how-to-use-the-cholesky-decomposition-or-an-alternative-for-correlated-data-si)

Subsequently, these random standard-normal variables could be converted into your Brownian motion and beta-distribution variables. Distance travelled in Brownian motion typically follows a normal distribution with a specific variance, so would just require rescaling one of the standard normal variables (or N, for N-dimensional motion). To convert one standard normally distributed variable to one following a beta distribution, use their CDFs -- i.e., if the standard normal variable is at percentile p, find the corresponding percentile p value for the Beta distribution in question. In R, for example, a standard normal quantity x would be transformed via

qbeta(pnorm(1.2),shape1=1,shape2=2)

This method of parametrizing correlation would not achieve a desired Pearson correlation coefficient, but would (I believe) result in a Spearman correlation equal to the correlation coefficient used in the first (Cholesky decomposition) step.

Comment: Hi Jwimberley, thank you for the answer! This answer becomes clear to me after I did some research. However, could you elaborate more why this procedure would result in a spearman correlation instead of Pearson correlation?

Comment: The function f(x2) = qbeta(pnorm(x2)) is monotonic but nonlinear. The correlation coefficient used to generate correlated normals x1 and x2 will make them tend to cluster around the line x2=x1, but applying the above transformation will tend to make them cluster around b = f(x1). The Pearson correlation coefficient between b and x1 would depend exactly on the shape of the function f(x).